# SYS AS SYSDBA user password forgotten

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sys

I have a sys as sysdba user of which password I have forgotten. I have a saved connection of the same in Oracle SQL developer, if I double click on it, I am able to connect it inside SQL Developer.

I want that password, I am exporting connection but the password is getting exported but in an encrypted way.

Can someone please help.

Comment: No idea about recovering the password, you may be able to reset it though: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_reset_sys_password.htm

Comment: I don't know what I am talking about here, so shoot me if I am off base, but... encrypted? I always thought passwords are hashed, not encrypted. If so, there's no way you can "recover" it, since only the hash of your password should be stored, not the password itself (encrypted or otherwise). SO: if I am right, resetting the password is the only option.

Comment: I don't know it is hashed or what, but while I export the connection it asks me for two things alright, one without password, second, export it with password setting the encryption key, so I may might just have used the word "encryption" but are we here to discuss the terminologies or having understood the problem, come up with some sort of solutions.

I know we can reset, but I am not having that option on the card, thanks anyways.

Comment: Another workaround: using your saved connection, create a new sysdba user with a known password.

Comment: How about just connecting with SQL Developer and changing the password?